# Search a filename for php

Tags: php, string, search

I wan't to search a filename for example like this string:

```
$filetype = "file.php.jpg";
```

And then i want to search if it finds php in that string, then return false;

Now if a filename is named php-logo.jpg i don't want it to be denied. Maybe we should consider searching for .php. in the string?

Comment: Pete, are you able to explain **why** you want to find the string 'php' in the string? Maybe there might be a better way. Thanks.

Comment: I changed my post now, hope it explains better now!

Comment: keep in mind that :
1) one can use a php online script to actualy create images (for instance a roll image, or information such as you know "your ip is")
2) it can be nasty
3) The one that uses php to generate image can also use mod_rewrite to give a jpg extension

I used to check the image width and the mime-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you complicate it so much? :)

```
    $file = 'some.php.file';
    if (false !== strpos($file,'.php')) {
       // file contains .php
       return false;
    }
    else {
      // file not php
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider the return value. Instead of returning false if it has PHP, why not return true if it does? What about this?

```
function containsPhp($string) {

    return strstr($string, 'php');

}
```

Then you could do this

```
$filetype = "file.php.jpg";

// does it contain php in it?

var_dump(containsPhp($filetype));
```

**UPDATE**

If you know for certain it will always appear as '.php.', then simply change the second argument of the strstr() function.

If you want the file extension, consider the following function.

```
function getFileExtension($filePath) {

    $filename = basedir($filePath); // this may not be required.

    return pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$filetype = "file.php.jpg";
if ( substr_count($filetype, 'php') > 0 ){

} else {
    return false;
}
```

[substr_count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

If you want check only the extension:

```
function get_file_extension($file_name)
{
    return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}
if ('php' == get_file_extension($filetype)) {

} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your first example, if i put a dot in front of php would that work?

Answer (score 0):

What if one sends php-logo.png?

Comment: Good point - Hopefully the OP can modify one of the other solutions to incorporate this.

Comment: Ah, yes that's quite a question! Then it would be denied by the examples below. Hm..

Comment: the question is: "search if it finds php in that string"